# How to find corresponding WMI/COM object for any given Windows Registry key?

Tags: windows, winapi, com, wmi

How to find corresponding WMI/COM object for **any** given Windows Registry key? Is there any useful table of this mapping on the web or function in the API?

(Saying "any" I mean any, for which such a mapping exists.)

**Edit:**

I'm asking because I have discovered that some WMI objects reflect their values to the Windows Registry keys.

For example there is mapping from

```
root\cimv2:Win32_OSRecoveryConfiguration.AutoReboot
```

to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl\AutoReboot
```

Comment: Which registry key?  The question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: I thought in general any key. It can be for example:"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\verbosestatus". But it is only an example.

Comment: Do you want to obtain a registry moniker? I believe that such implementation is not provided.

Comment: I tried to explain it in the last clarifying edit of the question.

Comment: It is the job of WMI to hide the implementation details.  So Microsoft can *change* the implementation and not break any code.  You are asking for the opposite, you want to know the forbidden knowledge.  The kind that you should *never* want to know because as soon as you do, something will break some day.  Your question cannot (and should not) be answered.

Comment: It must be my poor English, that no one understands me. I think that I’m asking for the _right_ knowledge: I know that some option is set by some Registry key. I do not want to set this key, I would like to set this option via (as you say) the "hiding WMI". Therefore I need to find the WMI object which sets the option. Really the question says that I’m looking for the opposite way? Can someone help me formulate it (in English) correctly, please?

Comment: @RadekHolý In that case, why would you have a registry key in the first place?

Comment: @Deanna Typically, trying to programmatically set up Windows, I start looking in the Microsoft’s documentation and searching the Web. If I fail, I start file system and Registry monitoring, I set the option manually (via GUI) and I see what has changed. Thus, I get the key first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the WMI part you can read the `MappingStrings` [qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the WMI class or you can use a tool like the [WMI Delphi code creator](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) to get this info.

[image]

Also you can read this article [`How obtain the source of the WMI Data`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/how-obtain-the-source-of-the-wmi-data/) to see a delphi sample code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It is what I’m looking for. Respectively, I’m looking for the opposite way, but this might help. Is it realistic to iterate over all WMI objects to find given Registry key in MappingStrings qualifier?

Comment: iterate over all the wmi classes will take some time, but yes you can do that and store the results in a text file.

Comment: I tried it and it looks usable. Since this seems to be the only way, I mark your reply as "my accepted answer".